# Collecting user data before PayPal purchase

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I've ran into a problem. Basically, I have a website that users can hire someone to tutor them. Each tutor has a small profile with a video, bio and rating. The user fills out a form with information such as their name, email and the **most important** one which is the date and timeslot (Dropdown) they want. When they fill out this information they can then click "Buy Now" which is a PayPal button I've setup. There are no variables here, each time slot is the same price all round.

**The problem I'm having is I don't know how to collect the user information when the PayPal button is clicked.** Can I pass this timeslot to PayPal who then return it to me? I can set up simple form that will send this information to me in an email, however I don't know how I can trigger that PHP script when the PayPal buy now button is pressed.

Any help? I've been Googling for a while, I can't seem to find anything! Maybe I'm wording it wrong. Anyway, hope you guys can assist.

Comment: Paypal has an API for doing this. It will route back to a page/url that you designate if the payment is successful, or if it fails. Just read their help docs. (Ps. Their help docs need help docs to help you reading their help docs....)

Answer (score 0):

I would save all of the info in your database prior to sending the user over to PayPal.  That way you can include the invoice number (or record ID) in the invoice parameter in payment requests.

If you're working with [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) the parameter is called invoice.  If you're working with the [Express Checkout API](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/overview-ec.pdf) it's called INVNUM.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Ajax in this situation. The ajax will prevent the redirect of the form to paypal for awhile but executes another process in which you will save and capture the information of the form to your database. After the process the redirection to paypal payment method will continue.

You can view this good tutorial in here. 
http://anytch.com/save-html-form-post-to-database-before-redirect-to-paypal/